# Best practice on initialising member variables

Tags: c#, windows-services, initialization

Is it better to initalise a private member variable for a service in the constructor like so:

```
public partial class DataPumpService : ServiceBase
{
    private TaskManager _taskManager;

    public DataPumpService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _taskManager = new TaskManager();
    }
```

Or just in the class like so:

```
public partial class DataPumpService : ServiceBase
{
    private TaskManager _taskManager = new TaskManager();

    public DataPumpService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

or is does it make no difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does make a bit difference. Both are initialized during object instantiation time (i.e. *you've a full guarantee that the class field will be initialized before the object can be consumed by other code*). What makes the difference is this ([a quote from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645759%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)):

> The instance field variable initializers of a class correspond to a
>   sequence of assignments that are executed immediately upon entry to
>   any one of the instance constructors (Section 10.10.1) of that class.
>   The variable initializers are executed in the textual order in which
>   they appear in the class declaration.

That is, if you got a class like the following one:

```
    public class A
    {
        public string text = "hello";

        public A()
        {
            text = "world";
        }
    }
```

...and you create an instance of `A`, `text` will retain `world`.

In my case, I use both approaches depending on the use case. Anyway, I tend to do the *initialization in the constructor* to gain clarity in terms of quickly discovering where class fields are initialized (*because other class fields should be initialized with a property setter instead of the class field directly... am I wrong!?*).

Comment: Thanks, sounds good to me. I'll leave it unaccepted for a bit though just in case someone knows something else but otherwise I'm happy to accept this :)

Comment: @Dan No problem, I don't expect to get my answers accepted, but give useful info :D If they're accepted, I get a good incentive about my knowledge, and I won't say *no* to get it accepted :D

Answer (score 0):

Almost no difference here. Use which way up to you.

But if you add one more constructor with parameters. Initialize member variable in the `class` will produces duplicated `IL` code for each constructor.

So, the best way to initialize when you have more than one constructor, put the *common initialization* in one constructor and let other constructors invoke this constructor by `this(...)`.